# HTM5 input field "date" doesn't work in mozilla, IE

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, mozilla

I have this form in Bootstrap,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputDate" class="col-lg-2 control-label">date</label>
       <div class="col-lg-3">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" required>
     </div>
</div>
```

which works only in chrome. Is there any simple way to get it work in mozilla or IE, or I have to built it from scratch?

Comment: The type = date is only a google idea as far as I remember. You may need to make your own using jquery or similar

Comment: use bootstrap date picker https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: It's not supported in Firefox, you'll need to use some form of plugin if you need this across all browsers

Comment: Its only supported in Google Chrome! http://caniuse.com/#search=date

Answer (score 2):

Seems you might have to build something for those browsers as support has not yet landed: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

And judging from the tables it doesn't look like Firefox will take it into account soon (same with IE and Safari).

Answer (score 1):

The date type is not supported in Firefox at the time of writing this answer, see
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/994340. As a bug report was raised as early as 2012, it seems unlikely this will be implemented anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not support input type date field yet.
I recommend you to use a Javascript datetime picker.
Refer [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)